# Google Charts domain annotationText not appearing (line chart)

Tags: angular, google-visualization

The following annotation text does not appear when mousing over the annotation. I am trying to make a domain level annotation. I was able to make it work on the individual data point, but I need the full vertical line (not point specific).

I think from the documentation, this should work.

Problem Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/j4fp3u2k/

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'x');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotationText'});
data.addColumn('number', 'Y');

data.addRows([
    ["-6", null, null, 1, ],
  ["-5", null, null, 2, ],
  ["-4", null, null, 4, ],
  ["-3", null, null, 8, ],
  ["-2", null, null, 7, ],
  ["-1", null, null, 7, ],
  ["0", 'O', 'i wish you could see me', 8, ],
  ["1", null, null, 4, ],
  ["2", null, null, 2, ],
  ["3", null, null, 3, ],
  ["4", null, null, 3, ],
  ["5", null, null, 1, ],
  ["6", null, null, 1, ]
]);

new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
draw(data, {
    curveType: 'function',
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    annotations: {
        style: 'line'
    }
});
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: first, you're using an old version of google charts, see [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code). however, the current version doesn't work either, you'll need to open an issue with google, nothing we can do...

Comment: i see what you're saying. That was just the library in the jfiddle that is found... i'll update, but in my actual implementation, i'm using the current... but I appreciate you looking at this!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the version update. I don't know why they changed it but it works fine with

```js
google.charts.load('49', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
```